# Create a basic .bashrc file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, linux-mint

I don't have `.bashrc` file, I want to create one but how? And what does a basic `.bashrc` file contains? I am on **Linux Mint 12**

I want to have a `.bashrc` file, because i have created a folder for `virtualenv` and I want to load `virtualenvwrapper`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `.bashrc` file contains whatever default settings you want to use when you are using `bash`.  If you don't have any particular preferences then leave it blank for now.

Typical contents of a .bashrc file includes aliases of commands you find yourself using a lot.

Comment: And you need to use some editor to fill your `.bashrc` file

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want one if you don't know what to put in there? You only need a `.bashrc` (or `.profile` or `.bash_profile`) if you actually have something you want to execute in every shell (or login shell).

But you can basically put any bash commands in those files.

Comment: please read my edit...and I'm new to linux, I didn't have to care about `.bashrc` on windows...

Comment: Not really an answer to what appears to be not really a worthy question.

Comment: @AoeAoe: It was until the user edited it to mention what he actually wants. Initially he just asked what he's supposed to put inside.